# Auto height not working on text based div in HTML

Tags: html, css, height, auto

I know this must be a very simple question but I am having trouble in auto adjusting the height of text based div. Basically I am displaying two horizontal divs in a row. One is text based and the other is image based. Image based div is always auto adjusting its height but text based div is not auto resizing its height accordingly. May be it is because of the padding I have added but don't know how to adjust it according to different screen resolutions. Please find the below two screenshots for better understanding.

Desktop View:
[image]

Mobile or Tablet View:
[image]

Below is the code for reference:

```
<style>
.container {
    display:block;  
    width:100%;
}

#custom-section2 .left, #custom-section2 .right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#custom-section2 .left {    
    background-color: #F7E3EC; 
    height: 464.67px;   
}
#custom-section2 .right {
    background-color: #FFF;     
}
.section2-with-text1{
    padding-top: 15%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.section2-with-text2{
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
.section2-with-text3{
    padding-top: 15%;
}
.section2-with-text3 .button {
    background-color: #000;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
.img-style{
    height: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1901px) {
    #custom-section2 .right img{
        height: 660px;
    }
    #custom-section2 .left{
        height: 660px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1900) {
    #custom-section2 .right img{
        height: auto;
    }
    #custom-section2 .left{
        height: auto;
    }
}
#custom-section2 .right img{
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
<div class="container" id="custom-section2">
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2200/5487/files/Rectangle_8.jpg?v=1582366707" class="img-style" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="section2-with-text1"><center>TEETH WHITENING KITS</center></div>
        <div class="section2-with-text2"><center>Get that insta-famous smile, from the convenience <br> from your home. Formulated with whitening <br> ingredients previously only available at your dentist.</center></div>
        <div class="section2-with-text3"><center><button class="button">SHOP NOW</button></center></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest a possible solution. I would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Let me know if my answer below solved your problem, thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you for prompt response. It is showing correct in your snippet. On my side, if I run it as an individual separate file it works fine but when I add it in my shopify's HTML section, it is displaying fine on desktop view but still text block is not auto adjusting its height. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hmm, there must be some external CSS somewhere that is also affecting it.  You'll need to use the browser developer tools to inspect the css on each element. Can you provide a link? I can inspect it if you want.

Comment: Yes, please find this link: https://gddev.myshopify.com/

Comment: Yes, you have css code in there declaring `div.right {...  height: 464.67;)` and also you have a file from `timber.scss.css` defining `.left` and `.right` with `float: left !important;`.  My suggestion is to rename your left and right div elements to something like, `<div class="custom-left">` and `<div class="custom-right"> and then change your css to match those classes. I'll make a quick codepen to show you what I'm talking about. I'll drop the link in a sec.  Be sure to upvote/accept my answer if I have been helpful.

Comment: Please re check my link. I have changed the code according to your suggestions and it worked fine. Just a minor height issue is left. Could you please check? you will understand

Comment: Ahh yes, nice!  Yeah, now just add `display:block;` to the image element.  You could do, `.img-style { display:block; }.

Comment: Also you could add, `#custom-section2 { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }`

Comment: Perfect Bryan. I am really grateful to you for your assistance. Thanks a lot mate

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help, good luck! :)  have a great day. :)

Comment: Done. Have a nice day too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `float` to horizontally align your elements, it would be much easier to use `display: flex;`

Using `flex` will keep the left and right elements the same height.

Also note: You'll need to remove the `height: 464.67px;` declaration in `#custom-section2 .left` and remove `float: left;` from `#custom-section2 .left, #custom-section2 .right`.

**(see all my comments in the CSS code)**

Like so:  (run code snippet)

```css
.container {
    display:block;  
    width:100%;
}

#custom-section2 {
    display: flex; /*Add this!*/
}

#custom-section2 .left, #custom-section2 .right {
    width: 50%;
    /*float: left;*/ /*remove this!*/
}

#custom-section2 .left {    
    background-color: #F7E3EC;
    /*height: 464.67px;*/ /*Remove this!*/
}
#custom-section2 .right {
    background-color: #FFF;     
}

.section2-with-text1{
    padding-top: 15%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.section2-with-text2{
    padding-top: 5%;
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
.section2-with-text3{
    padding-top: 15%;
}
.section2-with-text3 .button {
    background-color: #000;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
}

/*.img-style{
    height: auto;
}/*

/* You can remove all this: */
/*@media only screen and (min-width:1901px) {
    #custom-section2 .right img{
        height: 660px;
    }
    #custom-section2 .left{
        height: 660px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1900) {
    #custom-section2 .right img{
        height: auto;
    }
    #custom-section2 .left{
        height: auto;
    }
}*/
#custom-section2 .right img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /*Add this!*/
    display: block; /*Add this!*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="custom-section2">
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2200/5487/files/Rectangle_8.jpg?v=1582366707" class="img-style" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="section2-with-text1"><center>TEETH WHITENING KITS</center></div>
        <div class="section2-with-text2"><center>Get that insta-famous smile, from the convenience <br> from your home. Formulated with whitening <br> ingredients previously only available at your dentist.</center></div>
        <div class="section2-with-text3"><center><button class="button">SHOP NOW</button></center></div>
    </div>
</div>
```